# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a project to deserilize an XML and read it to a database.

I have the following code:

```
query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = @NationalRegistrationDate";
        command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", myDate);
```

I get this error:

> must declare the scalar variable @NationalRegistrationDate

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Here is the rest of the code:

```
      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
           catch(Exception e)       
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DatabasConnection Done");
            DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;
            string LastChangedBy = "System";

            foreach (Person p in myPersons)
            {
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();
                try
                {
                    command1 = Avreg(p.UnregistrationReason, p.GivenNameNumber, p.ProtectedIdentity, p.CitizenshipDate, p.NationalRegistrationDate, connection);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", p.NationalRegistrationCountyCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", p.NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", p.NationalRegistrationPostCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", p.NationalRegistrationCity ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", p.BirthCountyCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationDate", p.UnregistrationDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", p.BirthParish ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", p.CitizenshipCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", p.CitizenshipDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", p.NationalRegistrationDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress1", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress2", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress3", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignBirthCity", p.ForeignBirthCity ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedBy", LastChangedBy);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);

                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.WriteLine("Alla fält uppdaterade");

    Console.ReadKey();

         }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.Write(" ---- FEL VID INLÄSNINGEN ------  " + e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }






    public static SqlCommand Avreg(string s, string t, string p, string c, string d, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        try
        {


        var query = "UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, "+
            "LastName = @LastName, " +
            "NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, " +
            "NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, " +
            "NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1, " +
            "NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, " +
            "UnregistrationDate = @UnregistrationDate, " +
            "NationalRegistrationPostCode = @NationalRegistrationPostCode, " +
            "NationalRegistrationCity = @NationalRegistrationCity, " +
            "BirthCountyCode = @BirthCountyCode, " +
            "BirthParish = @BirthParish, " +
            "CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress1, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress2, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress3, " +
            "ForeignBirthCity = @ForeignBirthCity, " +
            "LastChangedBy = @LastChangedBy, " +
            "LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate";

        SqlCommand command1;



        if (c == "0")
        {
            query += ", CitizenshipDate = null";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);




        }
        else
        {
            query += ", CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", c ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

        }

        if (d == "0")
        {
            query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = null;";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        }
        else
        {
            query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = @NationalRegistrationDate";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", myDate);

        }


        if (p == "J")
        {

            query = "UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName ='Skyddad personuppgift', " +
            "LastName = 'Se hjälptext', " +
            "ProtectedIdentity = '1', " +
            "NationalRegistrationCountyCode = NULL, " +
            "NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = NULL, " +
            "NationalRegistrationCoAddress = NULL, " +
                "NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = NULL, " +
                "NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = NULL, " +
            "UnregistrationDate = NULL, " +
            "NationalRegistrationPostCode = NULL, " +
            "NationalRegistrationCity = NULL, " +
            "BirthCountyCode = NULL, " +
            "BirthParish = NULL, " +
            "CitizenshipCode = NULL, " +
            //"CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate, " +
            "NationalRegistrationDate = NULL, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = NULL, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = NULL, " +
            "ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = NULL, " +
            "UnregistrationReason = NULL, " +
            "ForeignBirthCity = NULL, " +
            "LastChangedBy = @LastChangedBy, " +
            "GivenNameNumber = NULL, " +
            "LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";



            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command1.Parameters.Clear();
            return command1;
        }

         if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            query += ", UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason";
            query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber ";

            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", s ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            query += ", UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason, GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            t = "00";
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", s ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
            command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

        }
        else
        {

                query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
                t = "00";
                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

                return command1;

        }
         return command1;

    }


    catch(Exception e)
{
    throw;
}

    }
```

Comment: There is just too much code. Can you narrow it down please?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Done

Comment: Why are you commenting out `//command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate"`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because I used that field already. Can't have it on two places, that would be duplicate.

Comment: There are many places where you all of a sudden do `command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);`. If you have added the part of the query where you have `query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = @NationalRegistrationDate;";` and then later do `command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);`, you have to re-add the parameter. Note: after the latest edit this is not obvious in the question, but in the first version it was there.

Comment: Every parameter in you query must also have a AddWithValue statement.  The AddWithValue is not a duplicate.

Comment: IMPORTANT: why are you using `ToString()` on `DBNull.Value`? That is very very wrong. You want to pass the actual `DBNull.Value`, otherwise *everything stops working*. If the problem is a casting one: try `whatever ?? (object)DBNull.Value` - that forces everything to object, allowing the cast to work correctly. For example: `p.FirstName ?? (object)DBNull.Value` or (just as fine) `(object)p.FirstName ?? DBNull.Value`

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, as you can see on my first code snippet, I do have code that adds the `NationalRegistrationDate`

Comment: This question needs to be reverted or further updated. The whole `Avreg` method needs to be included...

Comment: I'm also slightly concerned by the lack of a `where` clause here... just sayin'

Comment: @MarcGravell I removed that piece of code because PatrickHofman asked me to. I will reinsert it

Comment: @Simon.S no need, if (as suspect) Steve's answer is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic inside the AvReg method is flawed. The first `if` creates the SqlCommand but the second one recreates the sqlcommand removing the parameters added in the first if (Albeit this should give error on the @CitizenshipDate parameter.)

Anyway, create the command before entering the ifs and set the command text before leaving the method

```
public static SqlCommand Avreg(string s, string t, string p, string c, string d, SqlConnection connection)
{
    try
    {
        var query = "UPDATE ...."
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();



        if (c == "0")
        {
            query += ", CitizenshipDate = null";
        }
        else
        {
            query += ", CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate";
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? DBNull.Value : (object)c);
        }

        if (d == "0")
        {
            query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = null;";
        }
        else
        {
            query += ", NationalRegistrationDate = @NationalRegistrationDate";
            DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", myDate);
        }
        command1.CommandText = query;
        command1.Connection = connection;
    }
    return command1;
}
```

Said that there are other errors as pointed in the comment on your question, (like the DbNull.Value.ToString() as Mr. Gravell told you) and I would look to move all the parameters creation to be outside the for loop while inside the loop I would only change only the values.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();
command1.Parameters.Add("@PersonalIdentityNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
... add other parameters with the exact datatype here
foreach (Person p in myPersons)
{
    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        // Pass the command created above, not recreate another one...
        Avreg(command1, p.UnregistrationReason, 
                        p.GivenNameNumber, p.ProtectedIdentity, 
                        p.CitizenshipDate, p.NationalRegistrationDate);

        command1.Parameters["@PersonalIdentityNumber"].Value = string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
        .... set the values for the other parameters .....
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(.....)
    ...
}
```

Now the Avreg should not create the SqlCommand and return it, the mothod just uses the command passed as argument and add the required parameters only if they are not alredy present in the SqlCommand

```
public static void Avreg(SqlCommand command1, string s, string t,
              string p, string c, string d)
{

    var query = "UPDATE....";

    if (c == "0")
    {
        query += ", CitizenshipDate = null";
    }
    else
    {
        query += ", CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate";
        if(!command1.Parameters.Contains("@CitizenshipDate"))
             command1.Parameters.Add("@CitizenshipDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        command1.Parameters["@CitizenshipDate"].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? DBNull.Value : (object)c);
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but the fact is that I did that on purpose. If one field in the table is a specific value (`if (p == "J")`), then all the other fields must be null, that is why it recreates the sqlcommand if that condition is true.

Comment: The point is, do not recreate the SqlCommand, change the query text as you see fit. Also the Parameters is an SqlParameterCollection with all the method supposed to be present in a collection. So you could check for the presence of an individual parameter, remove it or clear everything.